# Postgresql trigger to insert a new record in table1 after an insert/update in table2

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, insert

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLKxm.jpg) database and I need to answer the following question:

"You need to create a trigger along with the function that will be executed when the trigger is fired. Every time that a patient is examined and there is a diagnosis (if the inserted appointment.diagnosis in not null), the patient's medical folder will be updated."

This is what I have come up with:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION appointmentsFunction()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $appointmentsfunction$
    DECLARE
        appointment_patientamka BIGINT := new.patientamka;
        appointment_cure TEXT := new.cure;
        appointment_drug_id INT := drug_id;
        appointment_diagnosis TEXT := new.diagnosis;
        BEGIN
        IF appointment_diagnosis is NOT NULL THEN
                INSERT INTO public.medicalfolder (patient,cure,drug_id) VALUES (appointment_patientamka,appointment_cure, appointment_drug_id);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$appointmentsfunction$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Which is the best practice/best way to do it?

PS. The patientamka serves as an ID for the patient. It could as well be patientID, but it's not, per my teacher's guidelines.

PS2.The medicalfolder table can include duplicate records for the same patient. So, i don't have to update the record with the patient's id (patientamka), I just need to insert a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Code Review question since I assume the above works, but anyway:

> `appointmentsFunction()`

Naming convention in PG is snake_case rather than camelCase. Also no need to append the word "function" to your function. Call it something that describes what it does.

> ```
> DECLARE
>     appointment_patientamka BIGINT := new.patientamka;
>     appointment_cure TEXT := new.cure;
>     appointment_drug_id INT := drug_id;
>     appointment_diagnosis TEXT := new.diagnosis;
> ```

I have two issues with this.

First you're going through the cost of assigning values to four variables (the cost is small but it's not free). Then you check if one of them is NULL, and if so you don't use those values - so you wasted the effort of reading and assigning all those variables.

The second thing is none of these variables are necessary because you can check if `NEW.diagnosis` is NULL, and if not, then INSERT the values (read directly from NEW) into `medicalfolder`.

Finally it would be nice to have `BEGIN` on the same indent as `DECLARE` and `END`.